# How to set up a delete confirmation modal in symfony 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner in Symfony and i want to set up a modal of confirmation of deletion in my Symfony 4 application. I wish this modal is present in all the pages thus to be placed in the file `base.html.twig`. Currently, I can recover my `id` but I do not know how to exploit it.

This is my twig template.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-theme v-middle display responsive nowrap" id="collaboratorTable"
               style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Téléphone pro.</th>
                <th>Portable pro.</th>
                <th>Agence</th>
                <th>Centre opérationnel</th>
                <th>Poste</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for collaborator in collaborators %}
                <tr class="" data-id="{{ collaborator.id }}">
                    <td>
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ collaborator.id }}</small>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="item-amount text-sm">
                            {% if collaborator.imageName is not null %}
                                <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(collaborator, 'imageFile') }}"
                                     class="rounded-circle mr-2" alt="" style="height: 25px"/>
                                {% else %}
                                <img src="{{ asset('images/collaborators/user-unknown.jpg') }}"
                                     class="rounded-circle mr-2" alt="" style="height: 25px"/>
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ collaborator.fullName }}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.emailAddress }}</span></td>
                    <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.professionalPhone }}</span></td>
                    <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.professionalCellphone }}</span></td>
                    <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.agency }}</span></td>
                    <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.department }}</span></td>
                    <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.titleJob }}</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="item-action dropdown text-right">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="text-muted"><i
                                        class="i-con i-con-more"><i></i></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-dark" role="menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                   href="{{ path('collaborator_show', {'slug': collaborator.slug}) }}">Consulter </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                   href="{{ path('collaborator_edit', {'id': collaborator.id}) }}">Modifier</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal" data-entity-id="{{ collaborator.id }}" class="dropdown-item deleteBtn">Supprimer</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Suppression</h4>
                        <p>Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet élément ?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnNo" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Annuler
                        </button>
                        <a href="#" class="btn w-sm btn-danger remove_item">Supprimer</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.deleteBtn').on('click', function () {
            let entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');
            $('.remove_item').attr('data-entity-id', entityId);
            console.log(entityId)
        });

        $(".remove_item").click(function () {
            let entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');
        });
    });
```

My controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/collaborator/{id}/delete", name="collaborator_delete")
 * @param Collaborator $collaborator
 * @return Response
 */
public function delete(Collaborator $collaborator): Response
{
    $currentUserRole = $this->getUser();
    if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $currentUserRole->getRoles(), true)) {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $manager->remove($collaborator);
        $manager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success',
            "Le collaborateur <span class='font-weight-bold'>{$collaborator->getFullName()}</span> a été supprimé avec succés");
    } else {
        $this->addFlash(
            'danger',
            "Vous ne disposez pas de droit de suppression sur les collaborateurs");
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('collaborator_index');
}
```

Comment: Im not familiar with symfony. Is it possible to render and return html in the controller ? Then you simply add some data attributes to your delete buttons, add an ajax call to your controller which returns the rendered modal template and in your success callback of your ajax call you open that modal.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution I thought of. But, I do not really know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image that the response of controller should appear right in the modal, lets say in the modal content area. Then modify the controller to this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/collaborator/{id}/delete", name="collaborator_delete")
 * @param Collaborator $collaborator
 * @return Response
 */
public function delete(Collaborator $collaborator): Response
{
    $currentUserRole = $this->getUser();
    if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $currentUserRole->getRoles(), true)) {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $manager->remove($collaborator);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->render('delete_successfull.html.twig', ['collaborator'=>$collaborator]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('delete_not_possible.html.twig');
    }
}
```

in file delete_successfull.html.twig you just place an alert box like this

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
        <p>
            Le collaborateur <span class='font-weight-bold'>{{$collaborator->getFullName()}}</span> a été supprimé avec succés
        </p>
    </div>
```

and your JS is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.deleteBtn').on('click', function () {
        let removeUrl = $(this).attr('data-remove-url');
        $('.remove_item').attr('data-remove-url', removeUrl);
    });

    $(".remove_item").click(function () {
        let removeUrl = $(this).attr('data-remove-url');
        $.ajax({
            url: removeUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            contentType: 'text',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('div.modal-content').html(data)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR){
                $('div.modal-content').html(jqXHR.responseText)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Consider that you need to pass not only the id of removed item but the remove-url, too. You need this extra data value on remove link:

```
<a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationModal" data-remove-url="{{url('collaborator_delete',{id:collaborator.id}) }}" class="dropdown-item deleteBtn">Supprimer</a>
```

This is not tested, but you should have an idea how it could work.